# PHP Loop Syntax Error echoing select

Tags: php, mysql, loops, select, syntax

I have a 3 stage if statement

if there are items already ordered, echo X , then add an extra field to add a single item if someone calls echo Y, then jquery to add more if more than 1 required Z

the problem i have is on the X, there is a drop down when ordering an item with a few options just hard coded with values 0,1,2,3,4 stored in the database, but show as the option in full text to save storing more info than necessary just easier to use numerical then show the value corresponds to it as everyone knows. However when i do, even though there are no syntax errors, i am getting the last option in the list repeated for each item i have stored, also it takes over all existing fields with the drop down field, with no drop down....code following...

```
$mCount = 1;
if(isset($_POST['fDetails']) && is_array($_POST['fDetails']) && count($_POST['fDetails']) > 0){
    foreach($_POST['fDetails'] as $fDetail){
        if(!empty($fDetail['title']) || !empty($musicDetail['location'])){

echo('
<tr>
<th colspan="3"><label>Item '.$mCount.'</label></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1"><label for="fDetailTitle'.$mCount.'">Item Title:</label></td> 
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" size="25" name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][title]" value="'.$fDetail['title'].'" id="fDetailTitle'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1"><label for="fDetailArtist'.$mCount.'">Item location:</label></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" size="25" name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][location]" value="'.$fDetail['location'].'" id="fDetailArtist'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1"><label for="fDetailitemStatus'.$mCount.'">item Status:</label></td>
<td colspan="2">
<select name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][arrange]" id="itemArrange'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" >
<option value="0". $fDetail['arrange']=="Entry" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Entry</option>
<option value="1". $fDetail['arrange']=="Exit" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Exit</option> 
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1"><label for="itemNotes'.$mCount.'">item Notes:</label></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" size="25" name="fDetails['.$mCount.'][notes]" value="'.$fDetail['notes'].'" id="itemNotes'.$mCount.'" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>'
);
```

Can anyone see the issue?

Code above added

Comment: I don't this this is the code fragment where your problem is.  Are you changing or iterating the value in $mCount ?

Comment: post the relevant code here pls, where you iterate and where you have the if statements.

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows you the line and the spot where the colors change.

Comment: @lolka_bolka i have added the code above for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error at this line:

```
 <option value="0". $fDetail['arrange']=="Entry" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Entry</option>
```

I dont know what you will do in the else-way but the `''.'` is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are ending your string on these two lines:

```
<option value="0". $fDetail['arrange']=="Entry" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Entry</option>
<option value="1". $fDetail['arrange']=="Exit" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Exit</option>
```

should be...

```
<option value="0" '. $fDetail['arrange']=="Entry" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Entry</option>
<option value="1" '. $fDetail['arrange']=="Exit" ? 'selected="selected"':'' .'>Exit</option>
```

I would suggest breaking this into smaller chunks rather than one large string.